# Check if value in Firebase Realtime Database is equal to String

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When a user logs in on my application, I want to check if the userType is a "Customer" or a "Venue Owner". This decides which activity is run next. Currently, the application crashes when attempting to log in.

Here is my Firebase Realtime database structure:

[image: two muppets]

Here is the related code:

```
public void loginUser(View v)
{
    if(e1.getText().toString().equals("") && e2.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Blank fields not allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(e1.getText().toString(),e2.getText().toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User logged in successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();


                            //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileActivity.class);
                            //startActivity(i);
                            DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                            mDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    //String userType = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                                    String userType = (String) dataSnapshot.child("userType").getValue();
                                    if (userType.equals("Customer")) {
                                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserMainPageActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(i);

                                    } else {
                                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(i);
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User could not be logged in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
    }
});
    }
}
```

As requested, here is the crash log:

```
01-31 13:35:14.348  5322  5322 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 13:35:14.348  5322  5322 E AndroidRuntime: Process: 
com.example.myapplication, PID: 5322
01-31 13:35:14.348  5322  5322 E AndroidRuntime: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean 
java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
01-31 13:35:14.348  5322  5322 E AndroidRuntime:        at 
com.example.myapplication.LoginActivity$1$1.onDataChange(
LoginActivity.java:66 01-31 13:35:14.348  5322  5322 E AndroidRuntime:        
at com.google.firebase.database.zzp.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
01-31 13:35:14.348  5322  5322 E AndroidRuntime:        at 
com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source)
01-31 13:35:14.348  5322  5322 E AndroidRuntime:        at 
com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source)
01-31 13:35:14.348  5322  5322 E AndroidRuntime:        at 
com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)
01-31 13:35:14.348  5322  5322 E AndroidRuntime:        at 
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
01-31 13:35:14.348  5322  5322 E AndroidRuntime:        at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-31 13:35:14.348  5322  5322 E AndroidRuntime:        at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-31 13:35:14.348  5322  5322 E AndroidRuntime:        at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
01-31 13:35:14.348  5322  5322 E AndroidRuntime:        at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-31 13:35:14.348  5322  5322 E AndroidRuntime:        at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:728)
01-31 13:35:14.348  5322  5322 E AndroidRuntime:        at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Here is the entire class:

```
    package com.example.myapplication;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText e1,e2;

FirebaseAuth auth;

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
}

public void loginUser(View v)
{
    if(e1.getText().toString().equals("") && e2.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Blank fields not allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(e1.getText().toString(),e2.getText().toString())
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User logged in successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();

                            //Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProfileActivity.class);
                            //startActivity(i);

                            String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                            DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child(uid);
                            uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    if(dataSnapshot.child("userType").equals("Customer")) {
                                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserMainPageActivity.class));
                                    } else if (dataSnapshot.child("userType").equals("Venue Owner")) {
                                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User could not be logged in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Add your crush log

Comment: Try debugging whether you are getting value of userType or not.

Comment: @TamirAbutbul I have added the crash log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.child("userType").getValue(String.class).equals("Customer")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserMainPageActivity.class));
        } else if (dataSnapshot.child("userType").getValue(String.class).equals("Venue Owner")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Using this code the user will be redirected to the corresponding activity.

Comment: Using this code, the application no longer crashes. However it is not opening the activities UserMainPageActivity or ProfileActivity. When you press login, the page closes but the app does not move forward, it goes back to the starting page.

Comment: In which place of your activity are you sing thise code? Can you share it? Is `onDataChange` even called?

Comment: made edit to my question to show the location of this code

Comment: I see now but you aren't using my entire answer. Your `DatabaseReference` is wrong. Change this `DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                            mDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()` with `String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child(uid); uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()`

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: I made the changes but the same problem persists. It closes the current activity and returns to the starting one.

Comment: Are you using any auth listeners?

Comment: My auth imports currently are      import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
and import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

Comment: At which particular line of code does that error occur?

Comment: I'm getting back the Toast "User logged in successfully" but it's not progressing to the next activity rather going back to the previous activivtiy.

Comment: Show me your latest version of your code.

Comment: Added latest code to bottom of question

Comment: If you add a log statement, any log statement inside `onDataChange` is it printed?

Comment: If the log statement is under     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { then it prints, but if it under either of the if statements, such as     if(dataSnapshot.child("userType").equals("Customer")) { it does not

Comment: Please see again my updated answer uisng  `.getValue(String.class)` does it work now?

Comment: It does! Thanks @AlexMamo

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the children of the datasnapshot. Since the response comes as child of datasnapshot.
Something like this.

```
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               String userType = (String) dataSnapshot.child("userType").getValue();
            if (userType.equals("Customer")) {
                       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                       UserMainPageActivity.class);
                      startActivity(i);

            } else {
    I          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                ProfileActivity.class);
                   startActivity(i);
                 }
             }
        }
```